# Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid + coil lag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

So i'm using LazyVertialGrid alongside coil to display some images, i have 3 fixed columns but whenever i scroll it gets pretty stuttery, almost unusable.
Am i doing something wrong or missing something?

I tried release mode, and lowering coil images resolution with no performance changes whatsoever.
I even commented the asyncImage line to see if coil was the problem, but even scrolling wasnt %100 smooth.

Edit1:
I checked the logs and saw this: https://gyazo.com/f292139703889495e5b4d385e170f425

Heres a video example of it: https://gyazo.com/ed7b4a9c7e1f4f256ad683d719ed62a7
I noticed that everytime i scroll down or up coil checks and tries to load an image (the loading icon), how do i prevent this behavior?

Edit2: Heres the code part of my lazyverticalGrid:
https://gyazo.com/14262effe8a2f6aa48b45fd1a7f7bb41

Comment: Hi, David! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Can you share your code? We can't give you any solutions if you don't share your code. Thanks!

Comment: Here it is [link] (https://gyazo.com/14262effe8a2f6aa48b45fd1a7f7bb41)

Comment: All relevant code along with errors and everything must be shared in proper way, not in links, pictures etc. Please read the rules before using SO.